# Como puedo asignar un formato personalizado a un dato Double en Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

Necesito dar un formato $00.00 , pero al tratar de poner:

```
Text("\((self.viewModel.accountByCustomerIdData?.amount ?? 00.00 ).currency) MXN")
```

ignora el primer cero y lo deja 0.00, mi amount es : Double

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes usar el siguiente formato:

```
"%05.2f"
```

Lo que hace el lado izquierdo del punto, es llenar con ceros hacia la izquierda hasta completar cinco caracteres incluidos el punto. Del lado derecho significan dos decimales.

```
"%05.2f" = 00.00
"%06.2f" = 000.00
```

En el código quedaría lo siguiente:

```
var miNumero: Double = 0.0

var body: some View {
    Text("$" + String(format: "%05.2f", self.miNumero)) //$00.00
}
```

Si cambias el valor de `miNumero = 3.5` imprime `$03.50`

Comment: Muchísimas gracias , con esto me quedo muy claro saludos